# Trying to decode dynamic JSON response

Tags: swift

I'm trying to decode the JSON response for all tags from the Pinboard API. I have a simple model I'd like to decode into:

```
    struct Tag: Coddle, Hashable {
        let name: String
        let count: Int
    }
```

The problem is that the JSON response I get is entirely dynamic, like this:

```
    {
        "tag_name_1": 5,
        "tag_name_2": 5,
        "tag_name_3": 5,
    }
```

So decoding into my model using `JSONDecoder.decode([Tag].self, data)` always fails.

Comment: But how would you extract the name and count  from the JSON structure you shown?

Comment: Also, a dictionary is unordered, while an array is ordered, so not sure you'll be able to have the decoded `[Tag]` in the same order as in the JSON.

Comment: That's precisely my problem. The returned JSON is using one of the values (tag name) as the key, so no way it seems to automatically extract the name and count.

Comment: Perhaps I simply can't use the automatic decoding Swift provides in this case, and just need to parse the JSON response manually into my model.

Comment: Decode is a `[String: Int]`, and convert that into `[Tag]` afterwards?

Comment: @Larme Indeed, I think that is probably the way to go. Just wanted to see if I was missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON can be decoded into a dictionary of type `[String: Int]`.

If you enter key and value of each entry of the dictionary into a `Tag` object, you can then sort the array of tags by `name`. Or you can sort the dictionary keys first, both work.

Catch: it will work ***only*** if the order of the JSON is also the order of the keys. It will NOT follow the order if the JSON arrives like this, for example:

```
{
        "tag_name_3": 5,
        "tag_name_2": 5,
        "tag_name_1": 5,
}
```

Here's the code (with two options):

```
    // First way:
    // 1) Decode the dictionary
    // 2) Sort the dictionary keys
    // 3) Iterate, creating a new Tag and appending it to the array
    private func decode1() {
        let json = "{ \"tag_name_1\": 5, \"tag_name_2\": 5, \"tag_name_3\": 5}"
        let data = json.data(using: .utf8)

        do {
            
            // Decode into a dictionary
            let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: Int].self, from: data!)
            print(decoded.sorted { $0.key < $1.key })
            
            var tags = [Tag]()
            
            // Iterate over a sorted array of keys
            decoded.compactMap { $0.key }.sorted().forEach {
                
                // Create the Tag
                tags.append(Tag(name: $0, count: decoded[$0] ?? 0))
            }
            print(tags)
        } catch {
            print("Oops: something went wrong while decoding, \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

```
    // Second way:
    // 1) Decode the dictionary
    // 2) Create the Tag objects
    // 3) Sort the array by Tag.name
    private func decode2() {
        let json = "{ \"tag_name_1\": 5, \"tag_name_2\": 5, \"tag_name_3\": 5}"
        let data = json.data(using: .utf8)

        do {

            // Decode into a dictionary
            let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: Int].self, from: data!)
            print(decoded.sorted { $0.key < $1.key })
            
            var tags = [Tag]()

            // Iterate over the dictionary entries
            decoded.forEach {
                
                // Create the Tag
                tags.append(Tag(name: $0.key, count: $0.value))
            }
            
            // Sort the array by name
            tags = tags.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
            print(tags)
        } catch {
            print("Oops: something went wrong while decoding, \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code works, here are little observations: the first solution could be also simplified with `decoded.map { Tag(name: $0.key, count: $0.value) }.sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name })`, no need to use `decoded[$0] ?? 0` then, since you don't access with value, but iterate over couple of key/value. Also, don't print `error.localizedDescription`, instead print `error` since it will give more info in case of failing. Finally, you can use `let data = Data(json.utf8)` (no need to force unwrap later).

Comment: @Larme: thanks for the tips! Creating the `Tag` directly inside the `.map` is actually simpler. Regarding the `error`, I frankly didn't know about the loss of information when using `.localizedDescription`.

Comment: About `error.localizedDescription`, it's a pretty common mistake. `localizedDescription` is more aimed to a user than a developer. And it can really be seen with `JSONDeccoder`, Replace `[String: Int]` with `[String: String]`, and `print(error)` & `print(error.localizedDescription)` differences should be flagrant.